# Show user if 'is_vendor' = 'true'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I created a users table and I have set up the user roles using boolean, see code below:

```
$table->id();
$table->string('name');
$table->string('email')->unique();
$table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
$table->string('password');
$table->boolean("is_admin");
$table->boolean("is_user");
$table->boolean("is_vendor");
$table->rememberToken();
$table->timestamps();
```

Now on my resource, I have a searchable input field, currently, it generates all users in database.

```
BelongsTo::make(__('Vendor'), 'User', User::class)
    ->searchable()
    ->sortable(),
```

What I wanted to happen is for it to only show users who are `is_vendor` based on user database.

Thanks so much!

Here's what I have tried but didn't work:

```
BelongsTo::make(__('Vendor'), 'User', User::class)
    ->searchable()
    ->sortable()
    ->search(function ($query, $search) {
        if (Auth::user()->hasRole("is_vendor")) {
            $query->where('id', Auth::id());
        }
    }),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Nova Resource, what you can do is remain using the original query you had,

```
BelongsTo::make(__('Vendor'), 'User', User::class)
    ->searchable()
    ->sortable(),
```

And add *dynamic related method* inside your Model like this:

```
public static function relatableUsers(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
    return $query->where('is_vendor', true);
}
```

Note: notice you must use method name in *plural format* as function name = *relatedUsers*

Here is documentation on it
https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/authorization.html#dynamic-relatable-methods